# can not retrieve data of navigation properties in EF 5, MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, navigation-properties

I have the following PersonelInCourse entity:

```
public partial class PersonnelInCourse
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PersonnelID { get; set; }
    public string CourseID { get; set; }
    public int HoursInCourse { get; set; }
    public byte IsApproved { get; set; }
    public byte IsPassed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RewardDetailID { get; set; }
    public string RejectReason { get; set; }
    public string FailReason { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual RewardDetail RewardDetail { get; set; }
    public virtual Personnel Personnel { get; set; }
}
```

I insert data like this and it has no problem:

```
...
PersonnelInCourse p = new PersonnelInCourse();
p.CourseID = id;
p.PersonnelID = User.Identity.Name;
p.HoursInCourse = 0;
p.IsApproved = 0;
p.IsPassed = 0;            
db.PersonnelInCourses.Add(p);
try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
...
```

I try to retrieve this info somewhere like the following. However, this causes an exception and I found out that all of navigation properties are null, so the exception throws:

```
@{    
var psic = new Models.PtDbContext().PersonnelInCourses.Where(p => p.CourseID == Model.ID);
var c = new Models.PtDbContext().Courses.Find(Model.ID);
int i = 1;
} // these all are ok.
...

@foreach (var p in psic)
{
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted black;">
        <td>@i.ToString()</td>
        <td>@string.Concat(p.Personnel.FirstName, " ", p.Personnel.LastName)</td> 
    //the exception throws from here, because the navigation property Personnel is null, and all other navPrs also are null.
        <td>@p.Personnel.Post.PostName</td>
        <td>@p.PersonnelID</td>
    </tr>

    i++;
}
```

How can I achieve what I want? Where is my mistake?

Comment: add `.Load()` to your queries, for explicit loading of the navigation properties.

Comment: where the model define on the top like `@model namespance.Models.Navigation`

Comment: I've disabled lazy loading and I also used this approach somewhere else and I have no problem there.

Comment: Is it code first? Can you add the mapping definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! (based on comments of @Liel):

```
var psic = new jqPersonnelTraining.Models.PtDbContext().PersonnelInCourses
    .Include("Personnel").Include("Personnel.Post").Where(p => p.CourseID == Model.ID);
```

dear Liel, you must add `.Include()` before `.Where()` ... Thanks a lot for your tips.

Comment: This solved such a big problem that I left incognito mode to sign in and up vote!

Comment: @Amin, I have used it before without .include and .load functions and it was working but now it is not, is it deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

You should add `Include()` for explicit loading of navigation properties.

`var psic = new Models.PtDbContext().PersonnelInCourses..Include("Personnel").Where(p => p.CourseID == Model.ID);`

This will load `PersonnelInCourses`and their `Personnel` in one query.

In case you need to load some more properties, simply chain more `.Include("")` clauses.

Comment: Ok. I also need info of another navpr within the Personnel(as you can see). Do I need to include that navpr too? if so, how?

Comment: Just add another `.Include("...")` to the same Query

Comment: I think you should write .Include before .Where

Comment: Have you tried my previous suggestion, of simply adding `.Load()` at the end of the query? It is supposed to do explicit loading of all navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping `PtDbContext` alive until you have finished processing data from it and explicitly test for the navigation property:

```
@using (var context = new Models.PtDbContext()){    
    var psic = context.PersonnelInCourses.Where(p => p.CourseID == Model.ID);
    var c = context.Courses.Find(Model.ID);
    int i = 1;
<table>
    @foreach (var p in psic)
    {
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted black;">
        <td>@i.ToString()</td>
        @if (p.Personnel == null)
        {
        <td><b>not found</b></td> 
        <td><b>not found</b></td>
        }
        else
        {
        <td>@string.Concat(p.Personnel.FirstName, " ", p.Personnel.LastName)</td> 
        <td>@p.Personnel.Post.PostName</td>
        }
        <td>@p.PersonnelID</td>
    </tr>
</table>
        @i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: DbContext is alive. In fact, this table is a preview of a report. The Personnel cannot be null! because the related foriegn key is not null. I must find a way to retrieve these navigation properties