# EF CodeFirst - Adding ICollection Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to figure out, how to implement navigation properties to my entities... But my navigation properties is always null:

I've set up two entities:

Entity 1 contains this lines:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BestellterArtikel> BestellteArtikel { get; set; }
```

My second entity looks like this:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BestellungId { get; set; }
    public Bestellung BestellteArtikel { get; set; }
```

Further more I included this line to my overwritten OnModelCreating-Method:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bestellung>().HasMany(e => e.BestellteArtikel).WithRequired(e => e.Bestellung);
```

What have I done wrong? Have I forgotten something important? And does it has to be so complex? Do I have to add a line in my overwritten method for each property?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution :

Entity 1:

```
  public virtual ICollection<BestellterArtikel> BestellteArtikel { get; set; }
```

Entity 2:

```
  public virtual  Bestellung BestellteArtikel { get; set; }
```

**Edited:**

also you have to revise your mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bestellung>().HasMany(e => e.BestellteArtikel).WithRequired(e => e.BestellteArtikel );
```

Instead of referring to BestellteArtikel property, you referred to type!

Comment: What name ? If you mean "virtual" it is a C# keyword, and using it in EF models means lazy loading the references.

Comment: Wait! there is something wrong in your mapping. I edited my answer

Comment: No, you havent understood me correctly: I have one entity called BestellterArtikel (take care of the R!) with property "Bestellung" and one entity Bestellung with the ICollection "BestellteArtikel" (without the R!)... I cant rename those properties like you did in your code... ;)

Comment: ok. sorry. But, if you do not want to use lazy loading, you have to tell EF, as Liel said, regardless of naming you used. did you apply "virtual" to referenced objects of models?

Comment: Yes, I used the virtual keyword and I want to use lazy loading :)

Comment: Wait a second. I included that reference property using ".Include(p => p.BestellteArtikel)" and it worked now. Is there a possibility to get it working without "Include"?

Comment: put your complete code where you used "Include(p => p.BestellteArtikel)"

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "always null"?
If you are talking about null values when you try to read them from DB,
then remember that you need to eagerly load the navigation properties when you query the context,
or use EF lazy-loading.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829007/can-not-retrieve-data-of-navgiation-properties-in-ef-5-mvc-4/16829172#16829172) for more information.

Comment: When I request my first entity with Find(1) (I created some example entities in the DB before requesting) and move my mouse over the navigation property "BestellteArtikel", its null and I cant expand it (no matter if lazy or eagerly loading), although I have 2-3 entites that should be in there.

Comment: var bestellung = db.AlleBestellungen.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1); thats what I try to do (using virtual keyword)

Comment: So, read my link and add `.Include("<property name>") to your query

Comment: working :) Is there a chance to work without those Include-Method? Or will that only work with eager loading?